# Find tiered fee portion of total amount with varying number of tiers

Tags: multivariable-calculus

An investor has $x$ amount of money that they wish to invest in the stock market.

The fees for investing are based on a tiered structure. Each tier has a ceiling, $c$, and a percentage $p$.

The fee for each tier is calculated based on the difference between the ceilings of the current and previous tier, or the remainder of the amount to be invested, whichever is lower.
$$b=\sum_1^n(min(a-c_{n-1},c_n)p_n)$$

The total fee is the sum of the fees of the individual tiers.

The sum of the investment amount, $a$, and the investment fees, $b$, cannot exceed $x$.

**Example**

```
 n |      c      |   p
---+-------------+-------
 1 |     250,000 | 3.50%
 2 |     500,000 | 3.00%
 3 |   1,000,000 | 2.00%
 4 |   2,000,000 | 0.50%
 5 | 100,000,000 | 0.25%
```

Given the above table of tiers, and an investment amount, $a$, of 1,750,000, the total fee, $b$, would be:

$t_1 = 250,000\times 0.035 = 8,750$
$t_2 = 250,000\times 0.030 = 7,500$
$t_3 = 500,000\times 0.020 = 10,000$
$t_4 = 750,000\times 0.025 = 18,750$

So $b=\sum_{n=1}^4(t_n) = 51,249.97$

This means that the investor must have a minimum amount, $x$, of 1,801,249.97 in order to be able to afford the investment.

**Question**

For any given value of $x$, how does one calculate the maximum value of $a$ such that $x=a+b$?

Comment: What do you mean a tier in this context ?

Comment: A tier is the value of $c_n\times p_n$. I've edited the question to reflect what their values could be.

Comment: Note that tier 2 has a width of $250,000$, not $249,999.99$ and so on.  That makes your numbers rounder.  It is curious that the second tier is at a higher rate than the first, but that is not a problem.  The fee on tier $2$ should be $8750$, not $7500$.

Comment: Noted, thanks. I accidentally transposed the rates of the first two tiers when I typed them in. I've edited to correct the typos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compute the minimum investment to get into each tier, just as you have done for the first three tiers.  The total for the first three should be $26,250$ so you enter tier $4$ at an investment of $2,026,250$.  If you are above that and still in tier $4$ you have $a=2,000,000+(1-0.005)(x-2,026,250)$  You can similarly calculate breakpoints for the other tiers.